# How to remove the extra space around the image inside a div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have images inside bootstrap card div which are inside col div

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 B">
      <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B">
        <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B">
        <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/3" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have image on all col div space.
[image]
How could I achieve that ?
[image]

How could I extend image in order to fill the gap that I represent by a black line

Comment: Did you tried removing the extra padding in `.col-*` classes?

Comment: What are you looking for?

Are just trying to show your image in col div with edge to edge?

Comment: your image should be `height:100%` you better try `background-image` with `background-size:cover` for a `card` div, and give `height:100%;width:100%` to the card div

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua yes I've tried it

Comment: @MancharyManchaary I thought doing this but I wonder why there's no way to have image cover all col div in bootstrap 4

Comment: @soniamaklouf before I answer to your question, please clarify that are you just want to consume the left and right space inside the col div around your images?

Comment: @soniamaklouf because image has its own resolution and in resizes depending on it, if  you make images `width:100%` the height will be calculated depending on images resolution, if you make `height` and `width` `100%` it will be distorted

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua not only the left and right space but also the bottom space

Comment: @soniamaklouf the answer that I provided will use the left and right space of the image according to your requirement but If you want to reduce the space at the bottom of your images, then either you have to align you image to bottom or you have to stretch it to fill the div.

Are you really want to stretch the image to use the space available at the bottom?

Comment: yes @SuhaibJanjua   I want the image cover all the div

Comment: @soniamaklouf Did you check my answer? Is that what you were looking for? or you can see [this image](https://ibb.co/j4kxqk) and let me know you are looking for that answer.

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua yes it's what I'm looking for but I have a last question. I've test your code and I see the last image with the girl have a bigger height than the two images above. Is there a way to make them have a same height with flexbox ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141626/discussion-between-suhaib-janjua-and-sonia-maklouf).

Comment: @Suhaib Janjua https://ibb.co/nt9qAk Is it possible to have the same height for the left images ? like 50 50

Comment: You want to apply 50% of row height to the above 2 images and the 50% to the below image?

Comment: @SuhaibJanjua yes

Comment: Yes you can do that. I have updated my answer again. Now it is exactly according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you describe you just want to consume all the space inside the col div (Left and Right blank space).

What you have to do is to reduce the default padding of bootstrap columns of `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px` to `0px`. And it will work for you.

Sometimes your styles get overloaded by the bootstrap styles. So in that case you have to use the keyword `!important` with your CSS property to overload all other CSS styles define for that particular property.

```
.zero-padding {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

And to force the image to use all the space inside the col div you have to use the following CSS.

```
.fill-space {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fill-space img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

In order to force the images on the right side to take the 50% of height to the above 2 images and 50% of height to the image below; you should use the following CSS.

```
.half-height{
    height: 50%;
}
```

---

### OUTPUT:

[image]

---

### Working Snippet below:

```css
.zero-padding {
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.fill-space {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fill-space img {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.half-height{
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 B">
      <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 row zero-padding">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B zero-padding half-height">
        <div class="card card-inverse fill-space" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B zero-padding half-height">
        <div class="card card-inverse fill-space" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 zero-padding half-height">
        <div class="card card-inverse fill-space" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/3" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used a little javascript to achieve this. Making the image hidden but using it as a full background.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.full-image').each(function() {
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + img.attr('src') + ')');
    img.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.full-image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 120px !important;
}

.full-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 B">
      <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B full-image-wrapper">
        <div class="full-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 B full-image-wrapper">
        <div class="full-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/4" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 full-image-wrapper">
        <div class="full-image">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/800/500/3" alt="Responsive image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will still work without JavaScript. You might need to do a bit more work to make mobile/tablet views optimal. I've had to force min-height to override bootstrap behaviour.